# wget - download all image links from a text file (on server) and download to folder on server

Tags: ssh, wget

I have a txt file on the server with hundreds of image links. All links are images.

I want to ssh and use wget to download all the links in the txt file into a folder on the server.

I have googled my brains out with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` has the `-i` switch. This way, you can let it read the URLs which it should download from a file:

```
ssh user@hostname 'wget -i imagelinks.txt'
```

This works if your file contains one URL per line.